# Change UIView Button Action

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a view with three buttons on it.

when any of them are pressed it calls a custom UIView with another button on it.

what i would like to do is change the custom views button to different actions, depending on what button called the new view.

hopefully this makes sense.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to dynamically create button for the custom view:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 10, 280, 100, 30 );
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
[button setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview: button];
if(//clicked button 1)
 {
     [button addTarget: self 
           action: @selector(action1:) 
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
 }
 else if(//clicked button 2)
 {
     [button addTarget: self 
           action: @selector(action2:) 
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
 }
else
 {
     [button addTarget: self 
           action: @selector(action3:) 
 forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
 }
```

Comment: this seems to be on the right lines, thanks for your help, but how would i know what button called the custom view?

Comment: put an integer in the custom view class, when you calls the custom view set the integer value to 1 or 2 or 3 according to the clicked button

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this to dynamically add actions to buttons:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc] init]
[button addTarget:self action: @selector(pressButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Hope that helps!